# type | undefined not assignable to type regardless of null check

Tags: typescript

In my following code i get a `Argument of type 'Definition | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Definition'.` error. But as you see i check the object value with `if (defs[type] != undefined)`. But at `this.addDefinition(type, defs[type]);` the error is thrown anyway.

```js
    public static addDefinitions(defs: Record<string, Definition>): void {
        Object.keys(defs).forEach((type: string): void => {
            if (defs[type] != undefined) {
                this.addDefinition(type, defs[type]);
            }
        });
    }
```

can it probably a wrong setting in my tsconfig?

Comment: Try using `typeof` to check if the value is `undefined`. For example, `if (typeof defs[type] !== 'undefined'`). Note that `undefined` here is written as a `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I could give a more thorough answer, but here's the solution TS may be expecting on a plain `Record<string,T>` object. (Take with a grain of salt: My guesstimate is that TS does not record `type` as a specific string, and even within the same flow it will "forget" it checked that key.)

```
    public static addDefinitions(defs: Record<string, Definition>): void {
        Object.keys(defs).forEach((type: string): void => {
            const def = defs[type] // fix the value to a variable

            if (def) {
                this.addDefinition(type, def); // def is defined
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I additionally found out that the active `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` in my tsconfig causes this error. i reported a issue on the typescript issue board. now lets see what the typescript team is saying about this and eventually fixing this